# undefined error with macro defined

Tags: c, macros

I am getting the following error:

> error: 'HFP_CIEV_CHELD' undeclared (first use in this function)

I have defined a macro at the top of the files like this-

```
#define HFP_CIEV_CHELD(n)           (UCHAR*)"\r\n+CIEV: 4," #n "\r\n"
```

and using in the function

```
switch(status->index)
{
    case AGABS_HFP_CALL_HELD_INDEX :
    Ag_send_data(HFP_CIEV_CHELD(status->dwCievStatus),(UCHAR)BT_str_len(HFP_CIEV_CHELD));
    break;
```

What is wrong in this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the line you have:

```
BT_str_len(HFP_CIEV_CHELD)
```

But your macro expects you to pass some arguments to `HFP_CIEV_CHELD`.

Comment: …so that reference to HFP_CIEV_CHELD` is not a reference to the macro and is left unchanged, ready to trigger the compilation error.